# Dual External Monitor Bumblebee/Nvidia (or withoout Bumblebee)

Tags: graphics, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, displayport

I have installed and configured Bumblebee on my Dell XPS 17 with an Nvidia GT555m.

I would like to use my two external monitors with the laptop closed, but it's giving me all sorts of difficulty.
Is there any way to do this?
I've seen methods for 3 monitor setups, but none for the two external monitors.

I would be equally happy to set up the monitors without Bumblebee.

One roadblock at the moment is that the Ubuntu machine cannot detect the HDMI to HDMI screen (Windows runs all 3 screens fine, so I don't think it's a hardware problem).